# Give an array as a value with OCI8

Tags: php, database, oracle

I make a pre-version of website with PHP and MySQL. Now, I need to change my database in Oracle. My question is : 
We have this type of query with MySQL/ PHP :

```
    $id = array("id" => $_GET['id']);
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM article WHERE id = :id';
    $requete = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    $requete->execute($id);

    $compteur = $requete->rowCount($sql);
```

So, I started to update my PHP code like this :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM article WHERE id = :id';
$requete = oci_parse($identifiants, $sql);
oci_bind_array_by_name($requete, ':id', $id, 1);
oci_execute($requete);

$compteur = oci_num_rows($requete);
```

Where $identifiants contains my login, password for my database. Now, he refuses to execute the query because he didn't accept an array as an argument on the line oci_bind_array;
So how can I upate the PHP query under Oracle ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add to your question the error you got - try getting the error with `var_dump(oci_error($requete));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `oci_bind_array_by_name` works with arrays (it means in the query there is a variable of type array) is different from `execute(array())` which work with associative arrays in order to set the values (in this case the query has non-array inputs).

In this case try `oci_bind_by_name` (assuming your connection is OK):

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM article WHERE id = :id';
$requete = oci_parse($identifiants, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($requete, ':id', $id);
oci_execute($requete);

$compteur = oci_num_rows($requete);
oci_free_statement($requete);
```